# Bibliography, comma for two authors, semicolon for three

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, punctuation

A journal I want to submit an article to has the following requirement for the bibliography: 
When it's two authors they're supposed to be separated by a comma plus the word "and".

Mayers, J., and Nichols, B.

When it's three or more, it's supposed to be a smeicolon between all authors and before "and".

Brown, A.; Cowell, P.; and Flint, P.

I've used `makebst` and all I could get is 
Mayers, J. and Nichols, B. (without the comma)
and 
Brown, A., Cowell, P., and Flint, P.(with commas, but not semicolons).

I suspect I have to change the bst file here:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
            'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            {
              bbl.and
              space.word * t *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
  if$
  nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
  namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
}
 while$
  } if$
}
```

But I have no idea how. Any ideas?

Comment: Would using `biblatex` be an option? Customizing `bibtex` styles is so much harder …

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You will need to provide a new `... {...} if$` clause to provide an explicit distinction between what needs to be done if there are exactly two authors and if there are more than two authors.

Comment: Thanks, Mico. I changed it to

     `if$`

              `numnames #2 =`

`{ "," * }`

`'skip$ `

`if$`

`numnames #2 >`

`{ ";" * }`

`'skip$`

That did it :)

Comment: @Alex - Glad my suggestion was fruitful. You should provide a full answer, so that your posting can be treated as having been answered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.